# IList<T> - Compiler Error CS0266 - Cannot implicitly convert type

Tags: c#, list, selenium, testing, automation

I'm doing an automation testing using C# and trying to cancel a request in our portal with specific conditions:

1. the status of the request should be `'pending for approval'` and
2. the type of the request should be in `'LNX'` to cancel the request.

But I'm troubled on how to fix the error in `IList<T>`

```
public void Cancel() 
{ 
    Tile.Click();
    wait = new WebDriverWait(BrowserFactory.Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10000));
    var reqStatusToSearch = "PENDING FOR APPROVAL";
    var reqTypeToSearch = "LNX";
    int rowNum = BrowserFactory.Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[name()='path' and @stroke-linecap='round']")).Count();
    IList<IWebElement> reqStatus = BrowserFactory.Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[name()='path' and @stroke-linecap='round']"));
    var webElements = BrowserFactory.Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[name()='path' and @stroke-linecap='round']"));

    int currentSelectedRecordCount = 0;
    int recordCoundToSelect = 1;
    
    while (currentSelectedRecordCount != recordCoundToSelect)
    {
        
        wait = new WebDriverWait(BrowserFactory.Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10000));
        var status = ReqNoTableElement.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[name()='path' and @stroke-linecap='round']")).ToString();

        if ((status.Contains(reqStatusToSearch)) && (status.Contains(reqTypeToSearch)))
        {
            var reqNumbers = ReqNoTableElement.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[name()='path' and @stroke-linecap='round']"));
            for (int index = 0; index < reqNumbers.Count; index++)
            {
                var element = reqNumbers[index];

                //Check if current element has a status of PENDING FOR APPROVAL
                var currentStatus = ReqNoTableElement.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[name()='path' and @stroke-linecap='round']"));
                if (currentStatus.Equals(reqStatusToSearch))
                {
                    currentSelectedRecordCount++;
                    element.FindElement(By.ClassName("mat-checkbox")).Click();
                    if (currentSelectedRecordCount == recordCoundToSelect)
                    {

                        CancelModal.Click();
                        wait = new WebDriverWait(BrowserFactory.Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5000));
                        Cancel.Click();
                        wait = new WebDriverWait(BrowserFactory.Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5000));
                        Confirm.Click();
                        wait = new WebDriverWait(BrowserFactory.Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5000));
                        return;
                    }
                }


            }
            if (currentSelectedRecordCount < recordCoundToSelect)
            {
                currentSelectedRecordCount = 0;
            }
            NextPage.Click();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Which line is causing you compile time error?

Comment: @nami-san, please provide the exception details

Comment: @PeterCsala the IList<IWebElement>

Comment: @PiotrM. what do you mean?

Comment: Have you tried to change `IList<IWebElement>` to `List<WebElement>`?

Comment: In what line do you get the error?

Comment: @PeterCsala yes, it also doesn't work

Comment: @PiotrM. in IList<IWebElement>

Comment: Just use ```var```, couldn't you?

Comment: @PiotrM. like this 'var reqStatus'? i tried running this also but its giving me the same result, the test explorer wont stop loading, i need to close the chrome tab first to stop the loading of test scenarios.

Comment: So, is it a compilation error or a runtime error? Using ```var``` won't cause the compilation problem.

Comment: It seems that we do have here XY problem. You are able to compile the code (when you use var) but there is some kind of another runtime issue.

Comment: `ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> reqStatus`

Comment: @RichEdwards i tried using the ReadOnlyCollection but the error now was on the ```BrowserFactory.Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[name()='path' and @stroke-linecap='round']"));```

Comment: @PiotrM. yes i was able to compile the code when using var, but there is another runtime issue and i can't totally see the issue because the test scenario wont stop loading.

Comment: Please, open Output tab and choose 'Show output from:' Test and provide the logs from there

Answer (score 0):

If you use Visual Studio, the intelisense tells you the expected return type for `find_elements`:

[image: findelementsIntelisense]

Instead of using:

```
IList<IWebElement> reqStatus
```

try this:

```
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> reqStatus
```

Comment: As I said earlier - it's a classic XY problem. The compilation problem was possible to solve using var but there is another runtime issue

Comment: @PiotrM. this is the result from Output tab

```========== Starting test run ==========
NUnit Adapter 3.17.0.0: Test execution started
Running selected tests in C:\Folder\ProjectName\FileName\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\FileName.dll
   NUnit3TestExecutor discovered 1 of 1 NUnit test cases
NUnit Adapter 3.17.0.0: Test execution complete
========== Test run finished: 1 Tests (0 Passed, 1 Failed, 0 Skipped) run in 2.3 min ==========```

Comment: Great, now could you provide the failed test error details?